# Backup SQL Server database to Azure with RedGate tools

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, backup, redgate

Is it possible to backup a SQL Server database directly to MS Azure with RedGate tools? I searched around and could not find any info on that.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: You might be better off posting this on dba.stackexchange.com. And you mean `Restore`, correct?

Comment: why don't you refer to their documentation or support team?

Comment: We have a good experience backing up SQL Server databases to Azure with SQLBackupAndFTP https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-sql-server-to-azure-storage

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't a service that Redgate provides (we used to a while back).

There are, however, other third parties, such as [CherrySafe](https://www.cherrysafe.com/) that cater for this scenario.